# Cannot Install Libc-bin?

Tags: dpkg

It won't install, what can I do? Here's what happens:

```
nathan@Big-Blue:~$ sudo apt-get install libc-bin
[sudo] password for nathan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,173 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,559 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libc-bin
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with sudo apt-get -f install (ldconfig not found)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603183/error-with-sudo-apt-get-f-install-ldconfig-not-found)

Answer (score 6):

It should help:

```
apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb unpackdir/
sudo cp unpackdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
```